# Storing .net procedure on Oracle database

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, procedures

I wrote c# procedure in visual studio express 2010 and i want to deploy it
in the database. As far as i know , oracle makes add-in for doing this, but in
express edition of visual studio i dont know how to add this add-in. Is there
a way for adding add-in in visual studio express edition,or there is other way 
of deploying them in oracle db ?

Answer (score 1):

VS 2010 Express does not support Add-ins 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7ef7fce3-76f4-41ad-b306-83b9dad5379e/where-can-i-get-addins-for-visual-studio-express